# How to change quantity of product in cart using REST API in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cart, api, rest-api, quantity

How to change quantity of product in cart using REST API in magento 2?

How can i change quantity of product listed in cart of magento 2 using api call ? (without changing order of items)

Answer (score 2):

> **How to change quantity of product in cart using REST API** ?

```
http://magento.host/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine/items/{item_id}
```

- `method : **PUT**`
- `Authorization : Bearer <customer token>`

**BODY**

```
{
  "cartItem": {
    "sku": "MH11",
    "qty": 1,
    "quote_id": "3",
    "product_option": {
      "extension_attributes": {
        "configurable_item_options": [
          {
            "option_id": "93",
            "option_value": 58
          },
          {
            "option_id": "141",
            "option_value": 168
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "extension_attributes": {}
  }
}
```

**FROM HERE WE CAN EDIT CART ITEM (Like `Qty`, `Attribute options` etc.)**

Comment: its adding new item to cart, not Changing Quantity

Answer (score 1):

Regarding reducing qty you have to omit the product_options whilst doing the PUT request to the endpoint (rest/V1/carts/mine/items/{item_id}):

```
"cartItem": { "sku": "WSH05", "qty": 5, "quote_id": "3" } }
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't do any error checking / handling, so you can set any amount of stock even if it isn't available:

```
"cartItem": { "sku": "WSH05", "qty": 101, "quote_id": "3" } }
```

[image]

I have created a github issue to see if this is intended behaviour or whether we should actually get an error message. (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12846)

Comment: still on it mate...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to change the quantity of a single item in a customer's cart, call:

> POST V1/carts/mine/items

With a payload similar to

```
{
  "cartItem": {
    "item_id": 5,
    "qty": 4,
    "quote_id": "6"
  }
}
```

Comment: if i call this it will add 4 quantities , and i call again it will add 4 quantities. its called adding. I not only want to increase quantities. i do want to decrease also. so, what should i do for decrease quantities in the cart.

Comment: Do you find a native solution for this ?

Comment: Do you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me to update (and overwrite, not increment) the quantity of an item in a guest cart via API call:

`PUT V1/guest-carts/:cartId/items/:itemId`

Body:

```
{
  "cartItem": {
    "item_id": :item_id, 
    "qty": :qty, 
    "quote_id": :cart_id_masked
  }
}
```

Perhaps the way item quantities were being incremented instead of overwritten is a bug that was fixed?

If you use the `POST` method, with a `sku` instead of `item_id`, then the quantity if incremented, I noticed. Not not when using `PUT`.

Comment: its adding new item to cart, not Changing Quantity