# How to update quantity of all products in cart with REST API

Tags: cart, rest-api

For updating a single cart item I am using a request like this:

```
PUT    /V1/carts/:cartId/items/:itemId
```

with body

```
{
    "cart_item": {
    "sku": "Some SKU here",
    "qty": 7,
    ...
    "quote_id": "1"
    }
}
```

However, this approach has several problems
 - It doesn't work as a single request for updating multiple cart items, which is my main problem.
 - It always adds quantity, but doesn't override, as mentioned [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142168/how-to-change-quantity-of-product-in-cart-using-rest-api-in-magento-2?rq=1)

I want to update the whole information once from client side, because it may not be convenient to request an update for each clicked button. Neither it's a good idea to send multiple updates at the end.

I'm new to this forum and Magento, please sorry for wrong formatting, and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be no way to update multiple items in a cart in one request. Despite the way the `cartItem"` body is structured as an object, it seems to only allow updating one item at a time.

There are two ways to do it, but neither support mass updates as far as I can see.

**Way #1:**

`PUT V1/carts/:cartId/items/:itemId`

Body:

```
{
  "cartItem": {
    "item_id": :item_id, 
    "qty": :qty, 
    "quote_id": :cart_id
  }
}
```

Note: With the PUT it seems, if you have the `:itemId` in the URL, you don't seem to need to `sku` or `item_id` in the `cartItem` body. You still need the `quote_id` though.

**Way #2:**

`POST V1/carts/:cartId/items`

Body:

```
{
  "cartItem": {
    "item_id": :item_id, // this will overwrite qty
    //"sku": :my_sku, // this will increment qty
    "qty": :qty, 
    "quote_id": :cart_id
  }
}
```

It appears, in my testing, that the "qty" does indeed overwrite the quantity, and does not increment or add to existing quantity, if you are using `item_id` in both the `PUT` and `POST` versions.

However, if you use the `POST` version, and use the `sku` instead of `item_id`, then it will add new items to the cart, effectively "incrementing" the quantity of that product. So watch out for that.

Comment: I got an issue is that qty is added not updated(use PUT). I try to remove sku but the behaviour is still the same