# How to increase/decrease items quantity of product in cart using REST API in magento 2?

Tags: api, rest-api

How to **increase/decrease** items  quantity of product in cart using **REST API** in **magento 2**

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163048/how-to-update-quantity-of-all-products-in-cart-with-rest-api call this api on one product update.

Comment: Using this api update product in quantity not increasing quantity of existing product, Any option to decrease product in cart

Answer (score 0):

You can use Update cart API [updates the specified item to the specified cart.]

```
PUT /V1/carts/{cartId}/items/{itemId}
```

$body data

```
{
  "cartItem": {
    "itemId": 0,
    "sku": "string",
    "qty": 0,
    "name": "string",
    "price": 0,
    "productType": "string",
    "quoteId": "string",
    "productOption": {
      "extensionAttributes": {
        "customOptions": [
          {
            "optionId": "string",
            "optionValue": "string",
            "extensionAttributes": {
              "fileInfo": {
                "base64EncodedData": "string",
                "type": "string",
                "name": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "downloadableOption": {
          "downloadableLinks": [
            0
          ]
        },
        "giftcardItemOption": {
          "giftcardAmount": 0,
          "customGiftcardAmount": 0,
          "giftcardSenderName": "string",
          "giftcardRecipientName": "string",
          "giftcardSenderEmail": "string",
          "giftcardRecipientEmail": "string",
          "giftcardMessage": "string",
          "extensionAttributes": {}
        },
        "configurableItemOptions": [
          {
            "optionId": "string",
            "optionValue": 0,
            "extensionAttributes": {}
          }
        ],
        "bundleOptions": [
          {
            "optionId": 0,
            "optionQty": 0,
            "optionSelections": [
              0
            ],
            "extensionAttributes": {}
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "extensionAttributes": {}
  }
}
```